# Multiplying Dask Dataframes results in NaN values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed

I am using dask.distrinuted, and I have two dask DataFrames A & B. Both have the same number of partitions, and each partition is a 2D DataFrame containing the same columns and rows that have float64 values. When I multiply the dask dataframes `A*B` and compute the results. I get a dask dataframe of the same size full of NaN values.

I tried computing a single partition of each dataframe individually as in:

```
A.partitions[1].compute()
B.partitions[1].compute()
```

And none of the two contain NaN values. I multiplied the two :

`A.partitions[1].compute()*B.partitions[1].compute()`

and I still get a dataframe of the same size that is full of NaN values. What could the problem be, why aren't I getting the actual results in float64? Note that other multiplicaion operations seem to work fine. Could it be related to the difference graph layers?

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a complete example that others can execute and investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by simply equating both columns of the dask data frames:

```
A.columns == B.columns
```

Even though upon inspection it seemed that the columns and rows had the same names and numbers and type, it seems that there has been an unnoticed discrepancy.